# Trying to access Azure Keyvault from .Net Framework project is hanging

Tags: c#, aes, azure-keyvault

I'm currently working on a 256 bit AES encryption API project for my job. One of the aspects of these encryption APIs is they need to access our Azure Keyvault to retrieve a key (we have different keys for different projects).

For some reason the .Net Framework project hangs when trying to access the key vault **after** the first successful execution. It will hang on this line: `var key = client.GetKeyAsync($"https://automationkeys.vault.azure.net/keys/{product}").GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

I have the same encryption API made using .Net Core and I'm able to execute calls multiple times in a row without issue.

After doing some reading I have a feeling it has to do with `async` / `await` but I don't know enough about all that to see where the problem is.

Here is my full **KeyVaultAccessor** class:

```
public static class KeyVaultAccessor
    {
        public static string GetKey(string product)
        {
            var keyValue = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var client = GetKeyVaultClient(<my_app_id>, <keyvault_cert_thumbprint>);
                var key = client.GetKeyAsync($"https://automationkeys.vault.azure.net/keys/{product}").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                keyValue = key?.KeyIdentifier.Version;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue))
                {
                    Assert.Fail($"Key was null or empty for product: {product}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Assert.Fail($"Error occurred while attempting to retrieve key for product: {product}. {e.Message}");
            }

            return keyValue;
        }

        private static KeyVaultClient GetKeyVaultClient(string appId, string thumbprint)
        {
            var keyVault = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
                X509Certificate2 certificate;
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

                try
                {
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                    var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
                    if (certificateCollection.Count == 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("<certificate name> not installed in the store");
                    }

                    certificate = certificateCollection[0];
                }
                finally
                {
                    store.Close();
                }

                var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(appId, certificate);
                var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientAssertionCertificate);
                return result.AccessToken;

            });

            return keyVault;
        }
    }
```

Comment: .NET Core doesn't have a synchronization context, but .NET Framework does so that is why you would be experiencing a deadlock here. Are you not able to refactor your code to be async?

Comment: Looking closer, you are using `await` in a method that is not marked async. This cannot be your actual running code, it would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure your root reason, but if you want to get a key in Azure keyVault by `ClientCertificateCredential` and local cert, try the code below which works perfectly for me:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys;


namespace key_vault_console_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var keyVaultName = "";
            var tenantID = "";
            var appID = "";
            var certThumbprint = "";

            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

            var certCred = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantID, appID, GetLocalCert(certThumbprint));
            var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(kvUri), certCred);
            
            Console.Write(client.GetKey("<your key name>").Value.Key.Id);

        }
        public static X509Certificate2 GetLocalCert(string thumbprint)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            try
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
                if (certificateCollection.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("cert not installed in the store");

                }

                return certificateCollection[0];
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Are you using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys and Azure.Identity in  a .NET Framework project? If yes, how did you get this working?